# DB table as a factory configuration

Tags: c#, design-patterns, database-design

We have some tables for domain type values, ie Customer Type, operation type etc..

it's built like: TypeID, Display,...

This way the web app can show the Display to the user and send the ID to the server side code, there it can be related to an enum or sent to a factory in order to create an instance by the ID.

I was thinking to add an information column for creating the Type (ie its type if assembly is loaded) so that the Activator could create the instance, this way I can narrow the configuration to just the above table.

before adding the column I have to define the types in the code specifically as well like so:

```
Factory.Register(id, typeof(MyClass));
```

if I will add that column I could make it :

```
Factory.Register(id, Type.GetType(StringValueFromDB));
```

it is working alright for me in the moment, so my questions are:

**is it following good principles?**

**does it have any kind of flaw?**

btw, each factory is a generic factory as mentioned [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8307/implementing-factory-design-pattern-with-generics)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132971/factory-design-pattern-getting-the-types-from-a-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need to store a type name in your table? From what I understand the `TypeID` is strongly linked to a `Type` in your codebase which `Factory.Register(id, typeof(MyClass));` defines just fine.

If you wanted to store the type name in the table for e.g. the ability to change implementations on the fly then perhaps your approach would be useful. But personally I think it is unnecessary as you would probably have to make changes to the rest of your code to accommodate any type changes you make anyway.

Comment: If I need to change the ID I only need to change it ine one place, plus I can add types from a different assembly, if I load it, though I doubt I will do it. Would you say it's unnecesary?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's unnecessary, especially if you are trying to create a plugin architecture which could make this approach easier to manage. I'm just saying that you should consider whether it is something you need to do. In my experience, there will usually come a point where a new requirement comes in which just won't fit this model which might mean a lot more work for you later. It's trying to find the right balance that is key.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more elegant to have an attribute like [Id("someId")] on your types, so that it can be discovered throught reflection without calling Factory.Register?

PS. I would post it as a comment, but I don't have reputation yet.

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean... can you please elaborate?